# How to get value of specific JSON object key in Jade

Tags: json, pug

If I have some JSON something like this (from an API):

```
"project": {
  "name": "Project Name",
  "modules": [
    {
      "id": abcd,
      "sizes": {
        "size1": "123",
        "size2": "456",
        "size3": "789",
      },
      "dimensions": {
        "size1": {
          "width": 234,
          "height": 345
        },
        "size2": {
          "width": 456,
          "height": 567
        },
        "size3": {
          "width": 678,
          "height": 789
        },
      }
    ],
}
```

I am able to get the `name` and `id` values, but am struggling to get the value of, for example `size3` from within `sizes`.

The closest I have got is

```
for prj in projects
  h2= prj.project.name

  for mod in prj.project.modules
    p= mod.id

    for val in mod
      p= val.size3
```

but that of course gives me both occurrences of `size3`.

My initial thought was:

```
for prj in projects
  h2= prj.project.name

  for mod in prj.project.modules
    p= mod.id
    p= mod.sizes.size3
```

but here `sizes` appears to be "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't quite achieve what I set out to, the following solution was suitable for my requirements:

```
for prj in projects
  h2= prj.project.name

  for mod in prj.project.modules
    p= mod.id

    if prj.project.modules[0]
      p= prj.project.modules[0].sizes.size3

    if prj.project.modules[1]
      p= prj.project.modules[1].sizes.size3

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should help, if its not exact, this is definitely the approach.

```
for prj in projects

 h2= prj.project.name

 for mod in prj.project.modules
   p= mod.id

   for size in mod.sizes
     p=size (or size.value or the like)

   for size in mod.dimensions 
     p= size.width
     p= size.height
```

Comment: Yeah, I also tried this @Vontei, but got `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined]`

Comment: Sorry, for `for size in mod.sizes`

Comment: I'm thinking because of the structure you may have to call each explicitly unless you can change the data structure to an array of objects, which would solve that problem.

Comment: Changing the data structure isn't an option I'm afraid. Could you give me an example of what you are suggesting?

Comment: Do you mean like `prj.project.modules[0].sizes.size3` `prj.project.modules[1].sizes.size3` etc?

Comment: "sizes": {[
       { "size1": "123"},
       { "size2": "456"},
        {"size3": "789"}
     ] },

Comment: I guess that's a suggestion as to how to change the JSON file? That's not an option in this case. I think something like prj.project.modules[1] p= prj.project.modules[1].sizes.size3 will work for me.